# IIS: ApplicationPool stops on web site access

Tags: iis, configuration, webserver, iis-7.5, iis-10

I have a strange issue. I searched almost through the entire web and got many clues. However, I am not able to solve the issue.

---Problem Description---
If I create a new site IIS default configuration creates and assigns a custom application pool to that site. For instance, if my site has the name **MyNewSite** the respective app pool that is created will have the same name. If I attempt to access the site the application pool stops/crashes and I will get *HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.* Additionally I observed that IIS attempts to create a directory with the name C/Users/**MyNewSite** but it vanishes shortly after it appeared. I remember I deleted these folders like these manually in the past without knowing they are related to IIS.

---Configuration---
Windows 10 - IIS 10

ApplicationPool **MyNewSite** uses Identity *ApplicationPoolIdentity* and Load User Profile is *true*.

[image: AppPool-Configuration]

The directory has the approbiate permissions for users
IUSR and IIS_IUSRS. Both have the same permissions.

[image: Directory Permissions]

The application directory is not located under the inetpub directory.

---Observations---

Running the site under App Pool **DefaultAppPool** seems to work. **DefaultAppPool** has the Identity *NetworkService* and Load User Profile is *true*.

Event Log shows following Error:

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WAS
Date:          24.05.2018 18:58:44
Event ID:      5002
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MY_PC
Description:
Application pool '**MyNewSite**' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Event Xml:
    
      
        
        5002
        0
        2
        0
        0
        0x80000000000000
        
        104222
        
        
        System
        MY_PC
        
      
      
        **MyNewSite**

---Attempts to solve the issue---
    - Reinstall IIS and Windows Process Activation Service.
    - Deleted Users in registry that corresponded to the user directories I removed accidently.
    - Additionally add IIS AppPool\**MyNewSite** and IIS AppPool\**DefaultAppPool** to folder permissions.

---Current Assumption---
It seems to be related to the virtual users IIS tries to create, but I don't understand why it fails to create them. I understand a workaround would be the NetworkService identity but it has worked before and I don't want to use this workaround forever.

Answer (score -1):

AppPool User Profile might be corrupt. solution was to delete the profile from System Properties|AdvancedAUser Profiles|Settings.

also try setting pool identity user password again 
http://www.yyosifov.com/2012/10/iis-update-application-pool-user.html

Comment: Which AppPool user are you talking about? If I delete it would IIS create a new one?

Comment: You are using APplication Pool identity , so if you go to system properties -> Advanced system settings -> User profiles . You can see it there

Comment: I think when the site starts again it will create for you , there are available steps in internet to re-create . I am suggesting the user profile might be corrupted and try this solution. You need to reboot machine after deleting the user